# How to tell ffmpeg -ss and -to to cut at keyframes (no re-encoding)

Tags: ffmpeg

From a video, I want to clip out a part I like. It's **roughly** from `12:34` to `43:21`, so I do:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -ss 12:34 -to 43:21 -c copy "output.mp4"
```

The result is cut exactly at those timestamps, not at keyframes, so I get a few seconds of audio with frozen image at both ends.

How do I tell ffmpeg to cut at closest keyframes?

I've tried putting `-ss` in front, like `-ss 12:34 -i "input.mp4"`, this does start the clip at a keyframe, but it makes `12:34` the new `00:00`, so `-to` won't work the same. Now I need to manually calculate the duration of my clip and put the duration after `-to`, but the calculation is too hard to be the best solution.

The [official wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Cuttingsmallsections) suggests using `-copyts` to maintain the original timestamps, but it messes up the timeline, and the progress bar in the player shows a wrong total video length.

There's also a `-noaccurate_seek` flag which sounds like what I need, but is actually not what it sounds.

(In case it matters, I'm using ffmpeg v6.0, input v=AVC and a=AAC)